# Merging raster data in QGIS using wildcards

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, wildcard

I have a problem merging raster data sets in QGIS, and I have searched various forums, but have not found a solution yet.
An "ordinary" merge, for example merging the raster files

height_tile1_average.tif,
height_tile2_average.tif,
height_tile3_average.tif

that are all within one folder works fine.

But, in the folder there are different tifs, such like

a) height_tile1_average.tif, 
height_tile2_average.tif,

b) height_tile1_maximum.tif "height_tile2_maximum.tif

So is there an option to merge only the a) *average.tif"-files, and after that only the b) *maximum.tif"-files using a wildcard?

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy with command line gdalbuildvrt http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html and gdal_translate http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html.

```
gdalbuildvrt average.vrt *average*.tif

gdal_translate of GTiff -co tiled=yes average.vrt average_mosaic.tif
```

Comment: +1, a lot easier than what I wrote in my post! =)

Comment: I just continued my raster processing. It works really fine! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the following script to your QGIS (Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script).

This script takes rasters from a single folder called "Test" on the Desktop and merges all "...average.tif" files and all "...maximum.tif" files. It then places the output rasters into the "Results" subfolder:

```
##Merge_Rasters=name

import os, glob

from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

path_dir = home + "\Desktop\Test\\"
path_res = path_dir + "Results\\"
#Create these folders or change the paths to fit your directories

os.chdir(path_dir)    #Sets current directory
average_input = glob.glob('*average.tif')    #classifies all files ending with "average.tif"
maximum_input = glob.glob('*maximum.tif')    #classifies all files ending with "maximum.tif"

for fname in average_input:
    processing.runalg("gdalogr:merge", ";".join(average_input) , False, False, path_res  + '/' + 'Average Result.tif')

for fname in maximum_input:
    processing.runalg("gdalogr:merge", ";".join(maximum_input) , False, False, path_res  + '/' + 'Maximum Result.tif')
```

You can change the script to fit your needs such as the location of the rasters, the options for the `merge` function etc.

Hope this helps!